# Can't obtain PHP variable from HTML form using CGI Python

Tags: php, python, html, forms, cgi

This is POST form:

```
<form method ="post" action="New.cgi">
<table>
<tr><td>Select: </td><td><select><option value = "<?php echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -2)?>">ID</option></select></td></tr><br> 
<tr><td>Allow: </td><td><input type ="text" name="Authorize" autofocus required="required"/></td></tr><br>
<br>
</table>
<input type="submit" name = "submitname" value="Add" />
</form>
```

PHP is used to obtain the last two characters of the URI - in this case, it is "tr".

This is `New.cgi` using Python:

```
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
ID = formData.getvalue('ID')
InputAuthorize = formData.getvalue('Authorize')
print(ID)
print(InputAuthorize)
```

Whichever value is inputted for 'Authorize' is printed correctly.
However, for 'ID', the output is `none`. So, obviously, I've made a mistake with my POST form code but I am unsure of what it could be.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you inspect the POST payload? Your `<select>` field doesn't have a `name=`.

Comment: @mario What do you mean? I have added a name and it makes no difference.

Comment: What if you add `id="ID"` to the `<option>`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- This doesn't change anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Altered part of POST form:

```
<tr><td>Select: </td><td><select name="ID"><option value = "<?php echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -2)?>" id="ID" >ID</option></select></td></tr><br>
```